# How do I paginate specific blog posts on Prismic and Nuxt?

Tags: pagination, nuxt.js, prismic.io

I am trying to paginate specific posts on my blog page with two `<a>` tags.

According to the [Prismic Pagination API](https://user-guides.prismic.io/en/articles/1401183-connect-to-a-custom-api), accomplishing that would be as easy as passing the parameter link `?page=1`, such as `example.com/blog/?page=1`, but nothing changes.

How can I [query](https://prismic.io/docs/vuejs/query-the-api/query-options-reference#30_0-page) the `page` option if I [cannot use a component instance](https://nuxtjs.org/guide/async-data/) to change it, which is inside the async function `asyncData()`?

`pages/blog/index.vue`:

```
<template>
  <div class="container">
    <h1>{{ title }}</h1>
    <h2>{{ content }}</h2>
    <section class="columns is-multiline is-centered">
      <article
        class="post box column is-3-widescreen is-4-tablet"
        v-for="(post, index) in posts"
        :key="index"
      >
        <nuxt-link :to="`/blog/${post.uid}`">
          <img :src="post.data.image.url" alt />
          <h3 class="title is-6">{{ Dom.RichText.asText(post.data.title) }}</h3>
        </nuxt-link>
      </article>
    </section>

    <!-- I want to PAGINATE my posts from here -->
    <nav class="pagination column">
      <a class="pagination-previous button is-black">&#x3c;</a>
      <a class="pagination-next button is-black">&#x3e;</a>
    </nav>
  </div>
</template>

<script>
import Prismic from 'prismic-javascript'
import PrismicDOM from 'prismic-dom'
import { initApi, generatePageData } from '@/prismic.config'

export default {
  data() {
    return {
      Dom: PrismicDOM,
      title: 'Blog',
      content:
        'Welcome to my blog. Browse through a streamline of tech tutorials that suits you needs.'
    }
  },

  head() {
    return {
      title: this.title,
      meta: [
        {
          hid: 'description',
          name: 'description',
          content: this.content
        }
      ]
    }
  },

  asyncData(context) {
    if (context.payload) {
      return generatePageData('blog_page', context.payload)
    } else {
      return initApi().then(api => {
        return api
          .query(Prismic.Predicates.at('document.type', 'blog_posts'), {
            pageSize: 3,
            page: 1
          })
          .then(response => {
            return generatePageData('blog_page', response.results)
          })
      })
    }
  }
}
</script>
```

Answer (score 1):

In order to get this to work, you're going to need to set up a [watchQuery](https://nuxtjs.org/api/pages-watchquery) to react to changes.  From the docs:

> Watch query strings and execute component methods on change (asyncData, fetch, validate, layout, ...)

```
// inside page.vue
export default {
  // Watch for $route.query.page to call Component methods (asyncData, fetch, validate, layout, etc.)
  watchQuery: ['page']
}
```

Now that the page is being watched, you can use NuxtLink to update the query string param.

```
<nuxt-link :to="`/blog?page=${page_num}`"
```

And while you do not have access to the component while inside asyncData, you do have access to the [context](https://nuxtjs.org/api/context) object

```
export default {
  asyncData (context) {
    return axios.get(`https://my-api/posts?page=${context.query.page}`)
    .then((res) => {
      return { title: res.data.title }
    })
  }
}
```